# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get a list from firebase document and then set to another empty List of maps then add a map to this list of maps and pass it back to Firebase.

This is My method:

```
Future logFinalWorkout(user, finalWorkout) async{
 List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> result = List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>();
await users.document(user.uid).get().then((doc){
  result = doc.data['finalWorkouts'];
  result.addAll(finalWorkout);
});
return await users.document(user.uid).updateData({
  'finalWorkouts' : result,
});
```

}

finalWorkout parameter is of type Map<dynamic,dynamic>
final workouts represents the list coming from Firebase. I keep getting the above error

Comment: did you notice your finalWorkout is from parameter ? what is its type ?

Comment: Yes it of type List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>

Comment: make sure this line `doc.data['finalWorkouts']` returns `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. As from the error, its look like it is returning `List<dynamic>`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> result` and add `List< dynamic> result` instead of that. Give it a try.

Comment: I tried with no luck, I have Map<dynamic,dynamic> wich i want to add to a list coming from FireStore